# How to get line from text file via findstr

Tags: batch-file, windows-7

How to get line from text file via findstr?

I expect to get this line for instance:

> 002-10.20.2.240 by input 002

I try this but it does not work...

```
@echo off
set /p line=""
set /p APP=numero de APP:

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /s /b "APP" Listin-7-4-2016.txt') do set line=%%a

echo. Linea del archivo detectada: %line%

pause
```

**Example of Listin-7-4-2016.txt**

```
002-10.20.2.240
003-10.20.3.240
004-10.20.4.240
006-10.20.2.241
007-10.20.7.240
008-10.20.7.241
016-10.20.6.240
017-10.20.6.241
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findstr /s /b "APP" ...` searches for the string `APP`, but you want to search for the variable `%APP%`:

`findstr /s /b "%APP%" ...`

(by the way: you don't need `/s` if you search in a single file only)

Comment: He should also change `set /P line=""` to `set line=`.

Comment: @rojo: depends on his intentions, but probably you're right.